# Validating SAS dataset

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to validate a dataset which has 100 variables and over 100000 records. I am importing data in string form (even for the numeric data). I observed some variables getting truncated in the end. How do I validate each variable to make sure that the data populated totally (not truncated)?

Sample data:

```
data dsn;
infile "xyz.txt" dlm= '|' RECFM=V LRECL=2000 PAD MISSOVER;
length
a1 $20.
a2 $100.
a3 $50.
;
input a1 $
a2 $
a3 $
;
run;
```

For example the string value is 1532564.7564 and I am getting 1532564.756 after my import. So, My question is this is the value that got is getting truncated. But, when I change it to numerical data then I would get the full value. Like wise, Licnum is character data (eg:12xd456) and this is getting truncated in the last digit ( shows up as12xd4).

Comment: Show some sample data and the log lines for the data step.

Comment: If you are using SAS/Unix, try some shell scripts to validate the load. Else, Consider to stage entire raw text file in a temporary dataset once this temporary dataset is established create new dataset with required columns from this temporary dataset.

Answer (score 3):

Try these adjustments

- Increase the `LRECL`
  Anything beyond 2000th character column would be getting clipped.
- Increase the `$` length of the variable getting clipped.
  The value `1532564.7564` is 12 characters and won't fit in a variable that is `$11.`
- Make sure any variables with a `$<n>.` format are not longer than `<n>`
  If you have `attrib Licnum length=$7 format=$5.` then only the first five characters will be seen when the data is viewed.